# Cannot import Flask-Paginate - python

Tags: python, flask

in my project in flask activating my virtual environment

```
install flask-paginate ($ pip install -U flask-paginate)
```

but when importing it

```
from flask_paginate import Pagination
```

in my project I get an error:

> The error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_paginate'

indicates that Python cannot find the flask_paginate module in my virtual environment, how do I fix this error?

I already tried reinstalling flask-pagination but the same error continues and when listing with pip list I get the correct installation but when importing I get an error

> Import "flask_pagination" could not be resolve

Comment: can u show the picture of the interface?

Comment: Seems like your project is not using the virtualenv. I would start by verifying the correct Python is being used to run flask